# Last insert ID with doctrine causes 500 error PHP

Tags: php, ajax, doctrine-orm, http-status-code-500

I have this web module on PHP we just migrated to PHP 7.2 from 5.3. We started using doctrine too and everything was working correctly. Suddenly the web module started showing random 500 errors. Not even on the same actions. I still haven't figured out why, however I could manage to trigger it every time using the function **lastInsertId** of doctrine. Every time it passes by that function it  throws a generic 500 error (Even if I activate errors on the php.ini I don't get any details on the error).

**Ajax call:**

```
function listaCandidatos() {
    $('#' + GLOBAL_ID).find('#candidates-button').click(function () {
        var btn = this,
            url = BASE_URL + 'actualizacion-candidatos.php',
            numInv = $('#' + GLOBAL_ID).find('#num_inventario').val();

        $(btn).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        $.post(url, {numInv: numInv}, function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                enableScannerForm();
                $('#' + GLOBAL_ID).find('#master_id').val(response.masterId);
                $('#' + GLOBAL_ID).find('#last_master_id').val(response.masterId);
                loadListScanner();
            } else {
                alert(response.message);
                $(btn).removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        }, 'json');
    });
}
```

**PHP action:**

```
   public function candidatos()
    {
        ILogger::info('ACTUALIZACION DE INVENTARIO OBTENER CANDIDATOS (INICIO)');
        $result = array('success' => true, 'message' => '');

        if (!Request::isAjax()) {
            $result['success'] = false;
            $result['message'] = 'No ajax request';
        } else {
            $pa_idpais = $_SESSION['pa_idpais'];
            $estacion = $_SESSION['estacion'];
            $modulo = $_SESSION['modulo'];
            $login = $_SESSION['login'];
            $mModel = new InventarioMaster();
            $dModel = new InventarioDetalle();
            $tModel = new InventarioDetalleTemp();
            $hModel = new InventarioHistorial();

            ILogger::info('EJECUCION DE QUERY OBTENER CANDIDATOS (INICIO)');
            $candidates = $dModel->getCandidates();
            ILogger::info('EJECUCION DE QUERY OBTENER CANDIDATOS (FIN)');

            $result['masterId'] = 0;

            if (count($candidates) > 0) {
                IDBConnection::getInstance()->beginTransaction();

                try {
                    $dataMaster = array(
                        'num_folio' => time(),
                        'id_courier' => 0,
                        'pa_idpais' => $pa_idpais,
                        'est_idestacion' => $estacion,
                        'mod_idmodulo' => $modulo,
                        'usu_login' => $login,
                        'inv_fecha_ingreso' => "CONVERT(datetime, DATEADD(hh, " . $_SESSION['pa_zona'] . ", GETUTCDATE()), 103)",
                        'inv_tipo' => 'ACT'
                    );

                    ILogger::info('EJECUCION DE QUERY REGISTRAR INVENTARIO_MASTER (INICIO)');
                    **$masterId = $mModel->register($dataMaster);**
                    ILogger::info('EJECUCION DE QUERY REGISTRAR INVENTARIO_MASTER (FIN)');

                    $tmpData = array(
                        'id_inv_master' => $masterId,
                        'id_inv_detalle' => '',
                        'gui_idguia' => '',
                        'pid' => null,
                        'inv_actual_checkpoint' => 'CC',
                        'temp_fecha_actual_registro' => "CONVERT(datetime, DATEADD(hh, " . $_SESSION['pa_zona'] . ", GETUTCDATE()), 103)",
                        'inv_status' => 'SE'
                    );

                    foreach ($candidates as $item) {
                        $tmpData['id_inv_detalle'] = $item['id_inv_detalle'];
                        $tmpData['gui_idguia'] = $item['gui_idguia'];
                        $tmpData['pid'] = $item['pid'];

                        if ($item['inv_checkpoint'] == 'SA') {
                            $tmpData['inv_actual_checkpoint'] = $item['inv_checkpoint'];
                        }

                        if ($item['det_tipo_ingreso'] == 'COU' && in_array($item['inv_status'], array('IN', 'AC'))) {
                            $tmpData['inv_actual_checkpoint'] = 'CC';
                        }

                        ILogger::info('EJECUCION DE QUERY REGISTRAR INVENTARIO_DETALLE_TEMP (INICIO)');
                        $tModel->register($tmpData);
                        ILogger::info('EJECUCION DE QUERY REGISTRAR INVENTARIO_DETALLE_TEMP (FIN)');

                        $dataHistory = array(
                            'id_inv_master' => $masterId,
                            'id_inv_detalle' => $item['id_inv_detalle'],
                            'his_checkpoint' => $item['inv_checkpoint'],
                            'his_checkpoint_candidato' => $item['inv_checkpoint'],
                            'his_fecha_registro' => $tmpData['temp_fecha_actual_registro'],
                            'his_comentario' => 'Sin escanear',
                            'usu_login' => $login,
                            'inv_status' => 'SE',
                            'his_evento' => 'ACT'
                        );

                        ILogger::info('EJECUCION DE QUERY REGISTRAR INVENTARIO_HISTORIAL (INICIO)');
                        $hModel->register($dataHistory);
                        ILogger::info('EJECUCION DE QUERY REGISTRAR INVENTARIO_HISTORIAL (FIN)');
                    }

                    IDBConnection::getInstance()->commitTransaction();
                    $result['masterId'] = $masterId;

                    $queueData = array(
                        'detalleIds' => '',
                        'lastGuia' => '',
                        'lastId' => '',
                        'lastMasterId' => $masterId,
                        'lastNumInv' => '0',
                        'lastRequestType' => '',
                        'lastRequestValue' => '',
                        'masterId' => $masterId,
                        'fromMasterId' => '',
                        'numInv' => '',
                        'numPiezas' => ''
                    );

                    ScannerData::setId('inventarios_scanner_actualizacion');
                    ScannerData::saveData($queueData);
                } catch (Exception $ex) {
                    IDBConnection::getInstance()->rollbackTransaction();
                    $result['success'] = false;
                    $result['message'] = utf8_encode($ex->getMessage());
                    $result['masterId'] = null;
                }
            }
        }

        ILogger::info('ACTUALIZACION DE INVENTARIO OBTENER CANDIDATOS (FIN)');
        echo json_encode($result);
        return;
    }
```

The error occurs in the register function:

```
$masterId = $mModel->register($dataMaster);
```

Which is this one:

```
public function register($data = array())
{
    $sql = "
        INSERT INTO 
            inventario_master
            (
                num_folio, 
                id_courier, 
                pa_idpais, 
                est_idestacion, 
                mod_idmodulo, 
                usu_login, 
                inv_fecha_ingreso, 
                inv_tipo
            ) 
        VALUES 
            (
                '" . $data['num_folio'] . "', 
                '" . $data['id_courier'] . "', 
                '" . $data['pa_idpais'] . "', 
                '" . $data['est_idestacion'] . "', 
                '" . $data['mod_idmodulo'] . "', 
                '" . $data['usu_login'] . "', 
                " . $data['inv_fecha_ingreso'] . ", 
                '" . $data['inv_tipo'] . "'
            )
    ";

    $this->db->executeQuery($sql);
   return $this->db->lastInsertId();
}
```

That lastInsertId just calls doctrine's function of the same name.

I have tried capturing the error, but failed to. The register function actually happens, and I do get the ID with the function however the ajax calls returns error everytime. I tried reading the error message from the ajax but it's empty. Also this does work on my local machine IIS. This is probably related to that server configuration but I'm not sure.

The server that's throwing the error is  Windows Server 2016 version 1607 with IIS Version 10.0.14393.0 and we are using Microsoft SQL server 2016 for the database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do logs reveal? enable error reporting also

Comment: Nothing in PHP error logs. Nothing in IIS logs either. I'm using E_ALL and we are tracking all errors because we are still in development, however this error in particular doesn't seem to show there.

Comment: So $this->db is a Doctrine DBAL connection object?  I know it is off topic but your register code is very scary and seems open to sql injections.  Maybe try moving to prepared statements just as a completely random guess.  I suppose you could also check to see if executeQuery is returning a statement object.

Answer (score -1):

Error 500 also may cause BOOM in files. Check for [BOOM](https://file.org/extension/boom)
You may try to return not lastInsertId but random number - error persist?